# TableCell - Memory Leak?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please have a look at the code below, which I have taken from the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rows.aspx):

```
Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Generate rows and cells.           
    Dim numrows As Integer = 3
    Dim numcells As Integer = 2
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 0 To numrows - 1
        Dim r As New TableRow()
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To numcells - 1
            Dim c As New TableCell()
            c.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("row " & j.ToString() & ", cell " & i.ToString()))
            r.Cells.Add(c)
        Next i
        Table1.Rows.Add(r)
    Next j
End Sub 'Page_Load
```

There is a new instance of TableRow for each row and a new instance of TableCell created for each table cell.  I have two questions about this:

1. How are these instances destroyed? i.e. `c = Nothing`. Surely there is a memory leak?
2. How does the Table class know where the instance of `TableRow` and `TableCell` is? The reason I ask is because it appears that you cannot reuse the instance of `TableCell` for multiple table cells and `TableRow` for multiple table rows i.e. you cannot do something like this:

   ```
   Dim objTable As New Table
   Dim objTableRow As New TableRow
   Dim objTableCell As New TableCell

   objTableCell.Text = "Test Row 1 Cell 1"
   objTableRow.Cells.Add(objTableCell)
   objTableCell.Text = "Test Row 1 Cell 2"
   objTableRow.Cells.Add(objTableCell)
   objTable.Rows.Add(objTableRow)

   objTableCell.Text = "Test Row 2 Cell 1"
   objTableRow.Cells.Add(objTableCell)
   objTableCell.Text = "Test Row 2 Cell 2"
   objTableRow.Cells.Add(objTableCell)
   objTable.Rows.Add(objTableRow)

   objTableCell.Text = "Test Row 3 Cell 1"
   objTableRow.Cells.Add(objTableCell)
   objTableCell.Text = "Test Row 3 Cell 2"
   objTableRow.Cells.Add(objTableCell)
   objTable.Rows.Add(objTableRow)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

.NET has a [Garbage Collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) that releases memory for you.

> The .NET Framework's garbage collector manages the allocation and
>   release of memory for your application. Each time you create a new
>   object, the common language runtime allocates memory for the object
>   from the managed heap. As long as address space is available in the
>   managed heap, the runtime continues to allocate space for new objects.
>   However, memory is not infinite. Eventually the garbage collector must
>   perform a collection in order to free some memory. The garbage
>   collector's optimizing engine determines the best time to perform a
>   collection, based upon the allocations being made. When the garbage
>   collector performs a collection, it checks for objects in the managed
>   heap that are no longer being used by the application and performs the
>   necessary operations to reclaim their memory.

If you need to release memory immediately (such as with database connections), you can Dispose of them, as long as they implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.
>   The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a
>   managed object when that object is no longer used. However, it is not
>   possible to predict when garbage collection will occur. Furthermore,
>   the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged resources such as
>   window handles, or open files and streams.
>
> Use the Dispose method of this interface to explicitly release
>   unmanaged resources in conjunction with the garbage collector. The
>   consumer of an object can call this method when the object is no
>   longer needed.

Comment: I realise that but in my experience it is always worth managing memory as much as possible.  I have problems with memory leaks in a .NET application.

Comment: .NET doesn't let you easily manage memory like you can in C++/COM. In my experience, .NET memory leaks are directly related to not disposing of disposable objects.

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, it is pointless in respect to "freeing resources".

Comment: Yes, that is what my answer is implying.

Comment: ok thanks.  Do you know why my second code fragment (see question) doers not work i.e. I could expect to see three rows and two columns, but I see one cell only.